# java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate3.HibernateAnnotationScanner.scan

Tags: java, hibernate, maven

I use Maven 3.3.1, JavaServerFaces 2.1, JPA 2.0, Spring 4.1.6, Hibernate 4.3.6, and I'm getting following error:

```
    16:11:34,464 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-4) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.persistenceunit."Project.war#org.hibernate.tutorial.jpa": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit."Project.war#org.hibernate.tutorial.jpa": Failed to start service
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1767) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_04]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_04]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_04]
    Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate3.HibernateAnnotationScanner.scan(Lorg/hibernate/jpa/boot/spi/PersistenceUnitDescriptor;Lorg/hibernate/jpa/boot/scan/spi/ScanOptions;)Lorg/hibernate/jpa/boot/scan/spi/ScanResult;
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.scan(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:723)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:219)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.spi.Bootstrap.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilder(Bootstrap.java:51)
at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilder(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:182)
at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilder(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:177)
at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:152)
at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:67)
at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:162)
at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.start(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:85)
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
```

My pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
      <version>4.3.6.Final</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
      <version>4.3.6.Final</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
     <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
     <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
     <version>3.5.5-Final</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
     <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
     <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
     <version>4.0.4.Final</version>
  </dependency>
```

In my lib folder I have:

- hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.4.final.jar
- hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar
- hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.6.Final.jar
- hibernate-infinispan-4.3.6.Final.jar
- hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar

Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the dependency on hibernate-annotations 3.5.5-Final. That is not needed in (and presumably is not compatible with) Hibernate 4.